# Calculate new column in pandas based on certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to multiple a two df based on certain values.

```
data = {'a':10,'b':20,'c':30} .
```

df1:

```
id,tag,factor
1,a ,20 
2,b ,22 
3,c ,25
```

my final result should look like something below:

```
id,factor,calc  
1,20,200
2,22,440
3,24,750
```

The steps I have tried but giving error.

> df['calc'] = df['factor'] * data.get(df['tag'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
df1['calc']=df1.factor*df1.tag.map(data)
```

Or do something different

```
df['calc']=df.factor*np.vectorize(data.get)(df.tag)#pd.Series(data).get(df.tag).values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1['calc']=df1.factor*df1.tag.map(data)
```

`df1.tag.map(data)` check the `data` dictionary values and replaces them by the associated key, thus giving you a new Series that can be multiplied by `df1.factor`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```
df['calc'] = df['factor'] * df['tag'].map(data)
df.drop('tag', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   id  factor  calc
0   1      20   200
1   2      22   440
2   3      25   750
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['calc'] = df['factor'] * pd.Series([data[key] for key in df["tag"]])
```

OUTPUT

```
   id  factor  calc
0   1      20   200
1   2      22   440
2   3      25   750
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension

```
df1['calc'] = [x.factor * data[x.tag] for i, x in df1.iterrows()]
```

Output is

```
   id tag  factor  calc
0   1   a      20   200
1   2   b      22   440
2   3   c      25   750
```